# How to avoid using to much if else?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is the concept of what I'm trying to acheive with the code. I want the user to be able to leave the login section whenever they press '0', the codes below works, but is there anyway that I can shorten these codes, cause I felt like there's too much if else being use.

```
def signup():
     print("Press '0' to return mainpage")
     firstname = input("Please enter your first name : ")
     if firstname == "0":
          print("Mainpage returned")
          mainpage()
     else:
          lastname  = input("Please enter your last name  : ")
          if lastname == "0":
               print("Mainpage returned")
               mainpage()
          else:
               username = firstname+lastname
               print("Welcome", username)

def mainpage():
     option = input("Press '1' to signup: ")
     if option == '1':
          print("Sign up page accessed")
          signup()
mainpage()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use early returns to remove some of the nesting.

```
def signup():
     print("Press '0' to return mainpage")
     firstname = input("Please enter your first name : ")
     if firstname == "0":
          print("Mainpage returned")
          mainpage()
          return
 
     lastname  = input("Please enter your last name  : ")
     if lastname == "0":
         print("Mainpage returned")
         mainpage()
         return

     username = firstname+lastname
     print("Welcome", username)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, write code that matches your true logic.  This potentially infinite recursion is inappropriate.  This is a nested process, not something innately recursive.

You say that you want to leave the signup area when the user inputs 0.  If so, then *leave* -- don't go down yet another "rabbit hole": delete those calls to `mainpage` and return normally.  After all, `mainpage` is where you came from.

As for using fewer `if` statements, you can't reduce this much without very much generalizing the interactions in your program.  You want to check for `0` in two places and for `1` in another.  This requires either 3 `if` checks or a process general enough to make all of the transitions given a list of legal "moves".  If you want that, please look up how to implement a finites state machine.

However, there is one straightforward economy: your user interface is unduly wordy.  Just ask for the entire name at once:

```
def signup():
     print("Press '0' to return mainpage")
     username = input("Please enter your name : ")
     if name == "0":
         print("Mainpage returned")
     else:
         username.replace(' ', '')    # remove space(s)
         print("Welcome", username)
```

Either way, this routine naturally returns to `mainpage`.